# How can I add a custom file association in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry

My concrete case is that I'm using Oracle VirtualBox and I want to be able to right-click the .vdi file and have the option "Compact" in the list (next to things like "delete", "send to mail", "send to zip", "open with", etc.).

I don't need help on how to compact a .vdi file. I know the shell command to do that. But I want to be able to do it without typing commands and use the context menu instead.

I searched all around the internet and found a tremendous amount of incomplete, outdated or contradictory information and I'm just lost.

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/) is exactly what you're looking for.

### Adding a new command to context menu of specific file type:

**Walkthrough:**

1. Open `regedit` and go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.vdi`.
2. Check the value of `.vdi` (`(Default)`), lets call it `vdi-val`.
3. Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vdi-val\shell`.
4. Create a new key named by your choice, this is the string that
   you'll see in the context menu. Lets call it `Compact vdi`.
5. Under `Compact vdi` create another key named `command`.

   - Now you're in the path `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\vdi-val\shell\Compact
     vdi\command`.
6. Set the default value to your program location with `%1` as a
   parameter - it's the file path.

   - For example, `C:\dev\compact_vdi.exe %1`

**Extra:**

- If you want to show this option only when holding `Shift`
- If you want to apply this to all files - put your `Command
  Title\command` under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell`

**More in the source:**

- Add context menu item to desktop context menu.
- Add to folder menus
- Creating a `.reg` file to do the changes.

Comment: Thanks. If only Google would have given me that link (or if only I knew the right combination of keywords to lead me there)

Comment: We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but please do not provide answers that are only a hyperlink.  While the information may be valuable, if the source web page ever goes offline the answer is essentially useless.  Quote all of the pertinent excerpts from the article within your answer, then you can still provide the hyperlink to cite your source.   Please see the following article from our Help Center:  [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Run5k Thanks for the feedback - I've updated my answer :)